# MPI behavior when building MPI_Group/MPI_Comm with ranks=[0,0]?

Tags: mpi, group, communicator

I'm trying to understand what would be the behavior of an MPI implementation (mine is OpenMPI 4.1.0) dictated by the MPI standard of this code :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <mpi.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    
    int idProc, nbProc;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&idProc);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nbProc);

    if (idProc == 0 || idProc == 1){
        MPI_Group worldGroup;
        MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &worldGroup);

        int* ranks = new int[2];
        ranks[0] = 0;
        ranks[1] = 0;

        MPI_Group intrfGroup;
        MPI_Group_incl(worldGroup, 2, ranks, &intrfGroup);

        MPI_Comm mpiComm;
        std::cout << "MPI_Comm_create_group before ! By proc " << idProc << std::endl;
        MPI_Comm_create_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, intrfGroup, 0, &mpiComm);
        std::cout << "MPI_Comm_create_group after ! By proc " << idProc << std::endl;

        int result;
        MPI_Comm_compare(mpiComm, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &result);

        if (result == MPI_IDENT) {
            std::cout << "mpiComm is MPI_COMM_WORLD." << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "mpiComm is not MPI_COMM_WORLD." << std::endl;
        }       
    }


    MPI_Finalize();
  }
```

It returns :

```
[ACH@is227051 bin]$ mpiexec -n 4 Allreduce 
MPI_Comm_create_group before ! By proc 1
MPI_Comm_create_group after ! By proc 1
MPI_Comm_create_group before ! By proc 0
[is227051:03157] *** An error occurred in MPI_Comm_compare
[is227051:03157] *** reported by process [3464888321,1]
[is227051:03157] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[is227051:03157] *** MPI_ERR_COMM: invalid communicator
[is227051:03157] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[is227051:03157] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

I tried `if (idProc == 0)` to let only proc 0, which is the only proc in the rank vector enter the if, but if I do that it just hang at :

```
[ACH@is227051 bin]$ mpiexec -n 4 Allreduce 
MPI_Comm_create_group before ! By proc 0
```

What I'm trying to understand here, is the behavior of MPI when you creates group/communicator from an array of int rank that list the ranks of the proc that you want to create a group/communicator but have doublons, ultimately just the same rank twice. I could not find anything in the MPI standard document describing this.

Comment: you are looking at the wrong droid.
On non zero ranks, `mpiComm` is `MPI_COMM_NULL`, and you cannot use it in `MPI_Comm_compare()` (see https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Comm_compare.html)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Oh ok, this I did not know, thks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually the answer was right [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Group_incl.3.php) in the documentation of OpenMPI :

> Each of the n elements of ranks must be a valid rank in group and all
> elements must be distinct, or else the program is erroneous.

Moreover, it is worth noticing that it also says :

> This implementation does not currently check to ensure that there are
> no duplicates in the list of ranks.

So the behavior I've got with my code is completely normal and now explained.

I hope this helps other people in the future.